# Attributed string image replacing text in UItextview

Tags: swift3, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I got an attributed string with an image in a textview, the attributed image is displaying fine. The issue is whenever I add the image it replaces the text inside the textview. I want to add the attributed image and then place the cursor at the end of the image, so that i can add text below the image. This is what I tried so far, thank in advance.

```
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = selectedImage
    let newImageWidth = (textView.bounds.size.width - 10 )
    let scale = newImageWidth/(selectedImage.size.width)
    let newImageHeight = selectedImage.size.height * scale
    attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: newImageHeight)
    let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    textView.textStorage.insert(myAttributedString, at: textView.selectedRange.location)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue my creating an NSMutableAttributedString() and add a new line attribute to put cursor to the bottom of the image. Hope this help someone.

```
var mutableAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = selectedImage
    let newImageWidth = (textView.bounds.size.width - 10 )
    let scale = newImageWidth/(selectedImage.size.width)
    let newImageHeight = selectedImage.size.height * scale
    attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: newImageHeight)
    let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    let text:[String:Any] = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]

   // Fixed my problem of having image replacing text, instead I place the text at the bottom of the image 
    let textAttr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "bottom of image \n", attributes: text)

    mutableAttrString.append(myAttributedString)
    mutableAttrString.append(textAttr)

    textView.attributedText = mutableAttrString
```